# Recompose Results of OpenCV RQDecomp3x3

Tags: opencv, linear-algebra, rotational-matrices, matrix-factorization, matrix-decomposition

After running [`RQDecomp3x3` in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=decomposeprojectionmatrix#rqdecomp3x3), you get:

```
mtxR – Output 3x3 upper-triangular matrix.
mtxQ – Output 3x3 orthogonal matrix.
Qx – Optional output 3x3 rotation matrix around x-axis.
Qy – Optional output 3x3 rotation matrix around y-axis.
Qz – Optional output 3x3 rotation matrix around z-axis.
```

How do you get back from the three rotation matrices (`Qx`, `Qy`, `Qz`) to the original input matrix?

Or in the case where the input matrix was a rotational matrix, `mtxR` will be the identity matrix so how can you go from the three rotation matrices to `mtxQ`?

*UPDATED*
With answer though I don't get why the transpose is needed.

Comment: transpose of a rotation matrix is same as inverse

Comment: original matrix should be mtxQ * mtxR, but I know it as QR decomposition, not RQ decomposition?!? So your question shoulf be how to get from Qx, Qy, Qz to mtxQ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like (at least for a rotational matrix input):
`input = (Qx @ Qy @ Qz)'`.